# Are cramps and muscle soreness caused by Lactic Acid?

Tags: medical-science, biology

I commonly hear that muscle cramps are caused by lactic acid.  For instance, this [article](http://www.24hrfitness.co.uk/fitness%20tips/muscle-cramps.html) indicates:

> Another cause of muscle cramps can be the build up of lactic acid in the muscles.

However, this [NYT report](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/05/16/health/nutrition/16run.html?_r=1) claims otherwise

> The understanding now is that muscle cells convert glucose or glycogen to lactic acid. The lactic acid is taken up and used as a fuel by mitochondria, the energy factories in muscle cells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Addressing the muscle soreness point, no, lactic acid does not cause delayed soreness.  Wikipedia has [a nice terse summary of why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acid#Exercise_and_lactate), backed up by this review (of multiple related studies).

> The lactic acidosis of exercise has been a classic explanation of the biochemistry of acidosis for more than 80 years. [...]
>
> This review presents clear evidence that **there is no biochemical support for lactate production causing acidosis.  Lactate production retards, not causes, acidosis.** Similarly, there is a wealth of research evidence to show that acidosis is caused by reactions other than lactate production. [...]
>
> It is only when the exercise intensity increases beyond steady state that there is a need for greater reliance on **ATP regeneration from glycolysis and the phosphagen system. The ATP that is supplied from these non-mitochondrial sources and is eventually used to fuel muscle contraction increases proton release and causes the acidosis of intense exercise**. [...] If muscle did not produce lactate, acidosis and muscle fatigue would occur more quickly and exercise performance would be severely impaired.
>
> — Abstract from Robergs, R A, F Ghiasvand, and D Parker, [Biochemistry of exercise-induced metabolic acidosis](http://ajpregu.physiology.org/content/287/3/R502.full.pdf)

The muscle soreness later, post-exercise, often felt the following day, cannot be caused by lactic acid as it is "[flushed from the muscle cells within 40-60 minutes](http://books.google.com/books?id=y7RhhbUN3x4C&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false)", though it is unclear if the blood stream carries it away or it is simply metabolized within the cell.

Cramping seems to be a more neurological symptom, when the peripheral nerves, rather than the CNS, generate a signal directing skeletal muscles to contract.  I can't find any papers that discuss lactic acid (which should be at a higher concentration with the muscle cells rather than extracellular) interfering with neurons or their receptors, so I don't know on that point.

Comment: Yes, I read the wikipedia article, in addition to these two:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramp, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness.  As you can see the three do not perfectly agree on what lactic acid does or does not do.

Comment: @Russell, the "lactic acid", and "delayed onset muscle soreness" article both say that lactic acid is not involved with a citation, while "cramp" lacks a citation.  In any case, how does that refute the review I cited?

Comment: @Nick -- It's nothing personal.  I know you're right with regards to the conclusion.  The downvote is for block voting wikipedia as a primary source.  I was attempting to illustrate in a less direct fashion why wikipedia is not a quality source.

Comment: fear the skeptic monkeys! :P

Comment: @Nick nothing personal here either.You were right with the conclusion from the beginning. But before the edit, you were being a poor advocate for your own position. Plus, I don't think you can base a response solely on wikipedia links. However because you now address the link between fatigue during exercise and perceived soreness later, this is much clearer statement. And with better links.

Comment: "The muscle soreness later, post-exercise, often felt the following day, cannot be caused by lactic acid as it is 'flushed from the muscle cells within 40-60 minutes'".  Seems to me that having acid on my muscles for a hour would cause issues resulting in lasting soreness.  I don't see how it being flushed away would prevent damage/soreness later.